# Solving $\frac{dx}{dz}-\frac{2x}{z}=1$

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

Please can someone solve this?

$$\frac{dx}{dz}-\frac{2x}{z}=1$$

Please this is only part of my homework question. I am stuckwith here. Please teach me this solution thank you:)

Comment: This is the simplest kind of differential equation there is. It's a first order linear ordinary differential equation. What are you having trouble with?

Comment: @Nrsnr: Hint, as Git said, this is LFO, so try Integrating Factor. Regards

Comment: Dear @GitGud I took ODE course 2years ago, so I forgot. Now I am taking PDE course. While doing PDE homework, I am constantly meeting this ODE solution. Please onlybone time can you show this? I need:(

Comment: Dear @Amzoti please show this only one time, because of the above reason I said GitGud.

Comment: @GitGud Your tone is off-putting. Please be kind, and leave your implied "you should know this!" at the door. What's "simple" to you is not necessarily simple to a newcomer!

Comment: @amWhy I didn't mean to sound rude, I'm genuinely trying to help.

Comment: @GitGud: I wouldn't say it's the simplest. It isn't separable.

Comment: Please can someone help me solving this? :(

Comment: @Nrsnr Given a non-trivial interval $I$ and $a,b$ continuous functions (therefore integrable) defined on $I$, consider the differential equation $y'+ay=b$. Let $A$ be an antiderivative for $a$. There exists $C\in \Bbb R$ such that for all $t\in I$ the following holds:
$$\begin{align} y'(t)+a(t)y(t)=b(t)&\iff e^{A(t)}(y'(t)+a(t)y(t))=e^{A(t)}b(t)\\
&\iff \dfrac{d}{dt}\left(t\mapsto e^{A(t)}y(t)\right)(t)=e^{A(t)}b(t)\\
&\iff e^{A(t)}y(t)=\int e^{A(t)}b(t)\,\mathrm dt + C\\
&\iff y(t)=e^{-A(t)}\int e^{A(t)}b(t)+Ce^{-A(t)}.\end{align}$$

Comment: @CameronBuie I really think this is simpler. With separable equations you need to deal with possible division by $0$ and then somehow justify there's no problem. The one in the question, however, is purely algebraic.

Comment: @GitGud: Fair enough.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

To elaborate on Amzoti's suggestion:

Here is a nice step-by-step solution to help you work through your problem.

[image]

Do take the time to study (refresh your memory) about [integrating factors](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx), and how to use them for problems of this type, so you can apply this technique to a wider range of such problems.

Comment: But you've just stopped him from doing so

Comment: I don't think so, @Michael. If this is an isolated problem (since the OP studied DEQ two years ago, and this cropped up in other work), a quick refresher is all that's needed. If the OP is hoping to solve a wider range of problems of this type, then he/she may want to review the linked website.

Comment: Than you Dear amWhy

Comment: You're welcome, Nrsnr!

Comment: + from an iphone

Comment: @Babak! Hello, dear friend!

Answer (score 2):

Hint: Try [*Integrating Factor*](http://tutorial.math.lamar.edu/Classes/DE/Linear.aspx):

$$\mu(z) = e^{-\int 2/z~ dz} = \dfrac{1}{z^2}$$

See referenced web site for examples if you are not clear on this technique.

Comment: Please can you write more explicitly?

Comment: Please see web site which has worked examples. Regards

Comment: Okay thanks Dear Amzoti

Comment: You got the ball rolling on this one! +1

Answer (score 2):

The homogenous equation is
$$\frac{dx}{dz}-\frac{2x}{z}=0\iff 2\frac{dz}{z}=\frac{dx}{x}$$
and by integration we have the  solution
$$x:z\mapsto Cz^2$$
and for the particular solution the function $z\mapsto -z$ is a remarquable solution so the general solution is
$$x:z\mapsto Cz^2-z$$

Comment: But at the first, not zero, this is equal to $1$

Comment: We solve at first the homogenous equation and then we look for a particular solution. This's a well  known method I think.

Comment: Thanks a lot Dear Sami Ben R.

Comment: You're welcome.