# First Order linear differential equation problem

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

I need help solving this DE:

$(\cos\theta )v'+v=3$

I really was only able to get it here:

$v'+(\sec\theta\ )v=3\sec\theta $

$I=e^\int\sec\theta\ d\theta$

Any help would be appreciated. Thanks

Comment: See my comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548999/solving-fracdxdz-frac2xz-1#comment1168454_548999).

Comment: @BabakS. When the OP doesn't interact I don't feel like being proactive.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint: It is separable.

Write it as:

$$\dfrac{dv}{d\theta} = (3-v) \sec \theta$$

Now you can integrate both sides as:

$$\int \dfrac{1}{3 - v}~dv = \int sec(\theta) d\theta$$

Can you take it from here?

Comment: Yes this is how i originally attempted it. However the answer I got from Wolfram is not equivalent to the answer I got (graphically). I forgot to include this was an IVP v(0)=1. My general solution was v(t)=3-C(sec + tan)

Comment: + Regards. :-))

Comment: @Matt Sounds like you integrated the left side incorrectly.  $\int\frac{dv}{3-v}=-\int\frac{dv}{v-3}=-\ln(v-3)=\ln\frac1{v-3}$

Comment: @Matt: Maybe you can add those details to the problem including the work you did, so we can have a look. Regards

Comment: @BabakS.: Thank you my friend! Hope you are having a beautiful Sunday! Regards

Comment: Im pretty sure i got it all figured out. Thanks again!

Comment: @Matt: You are very welcome, glad it all worked out! Regards