# Help solving first order differential equation ($\frac {dy}{dx}+\frac {2y}{x}=x^2$)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

can someone show me how to solve this equation and find $y$:

$\frac {dy}{dx}+\frac {2y}{x}=x^2$

I am not sure how to solve these sort of problems so a step-by-step on how to solve something like this will help me solve the other questions that I must do.

Comment: See my comment [here](http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/548999/solving-fracdxdz-frac2xz-1#comment1168454_548999) for a general step by step approach.

Comment: Thank you - I just needed something like that to help me understand the concept of integrating factors.

Answer (score 3):

Hint:

- Integrating Factor:

$$\displaystyle \mu (x) = e^{\int (2/x)~dx} = x^2$$

Comment: Perfect hint! +1